# using '@' in groovy JsonBuilder

Tags: json, groovy

I'm trying to construct the following json in groovy.

```
 {  
   "trace_id":123,
   "@timestamp":"455754534538",
   "body" : "abcd"
 }
```

Following is the code snippets I used to try this.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper 
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
def xmlPayload =  "payload";
def traceId = mc.getProperty('TraceIdProp');
def timeStamp = mc.getProperty('TimestampProp');
builder = new JsonBuilder()

def root = builder trace_Id: traceId, @timestamp: timeStamp, @version: 1, body: xmlPayload
```

However it seems I cannot use '@' character with the json builder, it's giving the following error.

```
groovy: 8: expecting an identifier, found '@' @ line 8, column 51.
    = builder trace_Id: traceId, @timestamp
```

Is this achievable in groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy, a `@field` has a special meaning. You should use a quote to use this character :

```
def root = builder trace_Id: traceId, '@timestamp': timeStamp, '@version': 1, body: xmlPayload
```